# Generating lists in a monadic context

Tags: list, haskell, monads

As I understand, you can use the 'draw from' `(<-)` keyword in haskell to take values out of a monadic context in do-notation:

```
func = do
    x <- getRandom
    let y = (x + 1)
    return y
```

How would I apply this when generating lists? Say I am mapping a function `f :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> m a` that takes an integer and returns a value in a `MonadRandom` context. I want to generate a list of values of type `a` inside a `MonadRandom` context i.e `m [a]` . I believe doing something like this:

```
func = do
    xs <- map f [0..10]
    return xs
```

would generate a list of values, each in a monadic context and then try to draw from the list which is not in the `MonadRandom` context

Apologies if my terminology/understanding is incorrect, I am new to haskell.

Comment: can you give an example for your `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### update

for your edit with the MonadRandom I think all you need is [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM):

```
import System.Random (randomRIO)

f :: Int -> IO Int
f n = randomRIO (n,n+n)

g :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
g xs = mapM f xs
```

example

```
λ> g [1..3]
[1,4,5]
λ> g [1..3]
[1,3,4]
λ> g [1..3]
[1,4,6]
```

btw: of course you can do this yourself using `do`:

```
g :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
g [] = return []
g (x:xs) = do
  r <- f x
  rs <- g xs
  return (r:rs)
```

just remember not to mix up the list and the `IO` monad here - so the `do`, `<-` and `return` here is in `IO` - for the rest of this answer it will be in the list-monad

---

First your example (if `f :: a -> [b]`) will create a *list of list of values* (which you surely found out already) - if you want to *flatten* it look below (basically you just have to pull out once more)

---

Right now I don't understand exactly where you are going for, but here is a short example of how you can use the `do` notation with lists:

Look at this function:

```
combs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
combs xs ys = do
  x <- xs
  y <- ys
  return (x,y)
```

here is an example of it in action:

```
λ> combs [1..3] "Hi"
[(1,'H'),(1,'i'),(2,'H'),(2,'i'),(3,'H'),(3,'i')]
```

As you can see the *trick* is to draw an *example* `x` out of all `xs` (of course you will do all - therefore you can think of this as working with combinatorics) and a `y` out of `ys` and then do something with them (here just make a tuple) and finally `return`ing it.

Now of course you can first map it somehow (here just doubling the `xs`):

```
combs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
combs xs ys = do
  x <- xs ++ xs
  y <- ys
  return (x,y)
```

and it will pull out of the mapped values:

```
λ> combs [1..3] "Hi"
[(1,'H'),(1,'i'),(2,'H'),(2,'i'),(3,'H'),(3,'i'),(1,'H'),(1,'i'),(2,'H'),(2,'i'),(3,'H'),(3,'i')]
```

does this help you?

---

here is another one where `f` creates a list itself:

```
func :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
func f xs = do
  x <- xs
  b <- f x
  return b
```

as you can see first we pull out an `x` from `xs`, apply `f` to get a lists of `b`s only to pull them out with `b <- f x` and then just returning those.

Which is of course just `concatMap`

#### Example

```
λ> func (\x -> [x,x]) [1..5]
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

is this where you are going for?

Comment: This helps a lot, I have added more detail to my question because I think it complicates the problem a bit.

Comment: oh ok - you are not talking about using the list-monad after all - I think what you are searching for is as simple as [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM)?